# How to Notify current lead owner when duplicate lead is created

Tags: duplicate-management, data.com

Using Data.com Duplicate Management: Matching and Duplicate rules, I want that when a duplicate lead is triggered:

- The duplicate lead will NOT be created in SF
- The original lead will get updated and it's owner get notified.

I am using the web-2-lead forms in order to capture new leads information.

Using the Allow/Alert/Report - I don't get the lead created ( I get notification in email that a lead could not be created) But the existing lead is not effected, nor it's owner alerted.

- When does a DRS and DRI are created? (I can create PB on it, but I don't see them created)